# How to have different microservices under the same website domain

Tags: docker, dns, microservices, hosting

Today I learned about microservices. I know that when working for a big corporation an API has to be devided in separate microSERVICES (auth, payment processing, etc). This is due to the fact that a single server might not be able to handle all requests, so we split them up and host those chunks of the API in separate servers.

Here is my problem... Say John logs in, so the auth request goes to example.com/login whose server IP may be 111.11.111:8080 port 8080. Cool, he is now signed in, that server is meant only for auth purposes, so when John is about to pay for the product, he sends a request to example.com/payments with the purchase details, but this web domain cant be assigned to 111.11.111:8080 because that is the ip of the auth server.

What do I do?

Comment: You don't expose any of your services directly to the public Internet.  Instead the `http://example.com` name routes to a load-balanced pool of reverse proxies that forward the requests to the internal service.

Comment: @DavidMaze do you know of any online article I can read to learn more about it? Or what to search in goole to find one?

Comment: @DavidMaze if what I am trying to do is have requests to different enpoints on different servers to abvoid overflowing one server, then that approach would not work since I would be overflowing the server that hosts the load-balancer pool. Right?

Comment: _Servers_, plural.  Also the reverse proxies aren't doing any real work but just forwarding requests, so you can have many fewer of them than backends.  You're searching for something along the lines of "production deployment architecture" (so, not really a programming question _per se_).

Comment: you may want to refer article here - https://microservices.io/articles/